# Reassign POST output variable

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a simple HTML form that when I hit submit. Posts it's data on the action page. What I want to know is on my action page is it possible I can output my select text and it's value?

For example when I hit submit on my form page. I want this data to go to my action page.

```
<form action="actionpage.cfm" method="post">
 <label for="emaillist">Email List</label>
 <select name="emaillist">
   <option value="test1@test.com">Test 1</option>
   <option value="test2@test.com">Test 2</option>
   <option value="test3@test.com">Test 3</option>
   <option value="test4@test.com">Test 4</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

so on my action page. I want the outputted selects value to go to the cfmails `to` and the selects text to go to the emails subject header so it'll show up as so.

**Subject:** Test 1: test1@test.com

I do not want Test 1 to be manually typed I want it outputted from the select tag that was submitted with the form.

I thought about reassigning the names value but that would also reassign value that it currently has when the form was submitted wouldn't it? Also I do not want to create another select box.

Comment: No, not without collecting that data via javascript and sending them to hidden inputs or submitting with ajax. that's simply not how html selects work.

Comment: Alright thank you. You gave me an idea I can probably collect the text of what the user clicked on for the option for the select tag and submit it to a hidden input that will post to the action page.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick things.

1. You need to add the `method="post"` to post data.
2. The web page sends over whatever is in the value field. If you want more data, you have to put it in the value attributes

   ```
   <form action="actionpage.cfm" method="post">
     <label for="emaillist">Email List</label>
     <select name="emaillist">
       <option value="Test 1 test1@test.com">Test 1</option>
       <option value="Test 2 test2@test.com">Test 2</option>
       <option value="Test 3 test3@test.com">Test 3</option>
       <option value="Test 4 test4@test.com">Test 4</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="SEND">
   </form>
   ```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the Post method. Is it possible to output the text from a option tag instead of it's value by any chance?

Comment: @Curious13 that's what happens when you leave off the value.

Comment: @Curious13. I suppose you could do some sort of Javascript manipulation onsubmit but all that is way more complicated than just having the value just be the value you want.

Comment: Yeah I think I should re-think this I've been trying to get that option text's not the value submitted to the hidden input but I'm having a bit of hard time trying to figure that out at the moment might have to come back to this in the future been on it for like 2 hours now.

Comment: Do you not have control over how the `option`s are created?